# frame() does not start a new plotting window on R under Windows

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I am trying to create a series of plots like this: I save a code (with a following structure) to a .R-file:

```
plot(...)
while (...)  {
 points(..)
}
frame()
barplot(..)
frame()
barplot()
```

and run it via "source path/to/file.R"

But somehow after all the commands are run, I have only one graphic window ("R Graphic Device 2 ACTIVE") which shows only the last barplot

I am using R 2.3 x86 under Windows 10

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting should happen?

Comment: Sorry.. Seemed "obvious" for me, that I would expect a NEW graphics window to be created, so that at the end of the script run I would have 3 windows with different plots

Comment: Try replacing each call to `frame()` with either `dev.new()` or `x11()`. Alternatively, you could use RStudio or call `layout()`.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns can you please provide this as an answer, I will approve it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace each call to `frame()` with either `dev.new()` or `x11()`. For other options, try using [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) or call `layout()`.

More detail: `frame()` is simply an alias to `plot.new()` and will result in the completion of the current plotting window (if there is one) and advance to a new graphics frame. `dev.new()` and `x11()`, on the other hand, will open a new graphics device.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. What is a "frame" then ? And can I access images from (previous) frames ? from UI or from code..